# IIS 10 .NET CORE SSL issue

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core

I am working on a simple site which has front-end and back-end server. Both servers are using the SAME SSL certificate. The SSL cert has DNS entries for FQDN and URL.

```
DNS=test.sample.com 
DNS=FQDN01.dev.sample.com
DNS=dataservices.sample.com
DNS=FQDN02.dev.sample.com

Tech Stack
Front end = ASP.NET Core 
Back End = .NET Core 
IIS 10. 
Windows 2016
```

When I call the data services from front-end it throws 404 error.

Then I removed certs from both the servers and added a new certificate which has only FQDN and no DNS for URL endpoint. Configured my code to call the data services using FQDN and magic - it started working!!!

Question - Are there any issues from .NET Core to use the same certificate on both servers? I am not IIS Admin or SME. Not sure how the bindings work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is the snippet which calls the dataservices from front-end:

```js
var handler = new HttpClientHandler(); 
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) => {
    return true; 
}; 
Client = new HttpClient(handler); 
BaseUri = AppConfiguration.Configuration["DataServices:ServerConnection"];
```

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question and format code properly

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem by adding SslProtocols and UseProxy